# pyqt application lost icon after packaged by cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt, cx-freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Images not showing when running a frozen pyqt app on another computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721953/images-not-showing-when-running-a-frozen-pyqt-app-on-another-computer)

I have a pyqt application whose icon is in a resource file. I can see the icon when run the application using python app.py. But after I package the application using cx_freeze, the icon is missing. I can see the compiled resource in the `library.zip' (generated by cx_freeze), but the icon is still missing. Any one can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I was using an .ico file for the icon. However when I used a .gif file for the icon instead, I got my icon back. Hope this helps.

If not, try not using the icon as a compiled resource, but just a normal file in its directory.