# Icon not showing once Pyside app has been built cxfreeze

Tags: python, pyside, cx-freeze

I have created an app and have added an icon to it. When I run my application through visual studio, the icon displays on the top-left hand corner as it should do. However once I build the application with cx_freeze the icon is visible on the exe file, however once i execute it the icon does not appear on the taskbar nor the top-left hand corner of the app.

here is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe=Executable(
    script="PythonMusicDownloader.py",
    base="Win32Gui",
    icon="resources/icon.ico"
)
includefiles=["controllers.py","models.py","views.py"]
includes=[]
excludes=[]
packages=["requests", "atexit", "Pyside"]
setup(

    version = "0.1",
    description = "Beta release of Music Downloader written in Python",
    author = "Unknown",
    name = "Music Downloader",
    options = {'build_exe'{'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}},
    executables = [exe]
 )
```

It is part of the following project:
https://github.com/Feverfew/PythonMusicDownloader

Does anyone know how I can get the icon to show once I have built it? I have looked online but I have not seen anyone ask a question like mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this and this. As a helpful hint, try a png or gif icon, or try PyInstaller. I've had similar issues before.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499902/pyqt-application-lost-icon-after-packaged-by-cx-freeze

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721953/images-not-showing-when-running-a-frozen-pyqt-app-on-another-computer

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. For me I put my icon in a resources folder. However it only works if I put it in the base folder where my startup script is, as when the application is built the resources folder is not recreated!! Thus why it works in debug but not when built.